# I will run an Italian restaurant near the beach in London

Tags: grammar

## 1. Someday, I will run an Italian restaurant near the beach in London.

There are two prepositional phrases in this sentence. One is 'near the beach'. The other is 'in London'. Is 'near the beach' an adjective phrase or an adverbial phrase? Is 'in London' an adjective phrase or an adverbial phrase? Would you explain them in detail? Do they have structural ambiguity?

Comment: Good luck finding beachside property in London.

Comment: May I suggest you simplify your sentence to *I run an Italian restaurant near the beach in [Malibu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malibu,_California).* The same question applies, and also it makes more sense, seeing how London has no beaches.

Comment: near the River Thames is more plausible....

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Climate change will address that issue :-(

Comment: I have found that many people world wide aren't sure of the difference between "London", "England", and "Britain", and quite a few think there isn't any.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet There used to be a "beach" in the Tottenham Court Road. I don't know if it's still there.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You are right. Some people around the world do speak of London as though it were Britain. I was once visiting a Malaysian businessman in Cheshire, and I heard him saying down the phone to someone in Malaysia - "this is Michael Chan here, calling from London".

Comment: I have an American friend who lives in Cornwall. Her mother in the USA used to say "How's London?" to her on the phone, and proudly tell her friends her daughter lived in "London, England". etc, despite my friend's attempts to correct her. Then Mom flew over to visit, and they had to take a train west from Paddington. Imagine Mom's surprise as the train kept going, and going, and going. Then the branch line to St Ives. Then the taxi for 10 miles. The journey took longer than the preceding flight from JFK. Now Mom says proudly "My daughter lives _way_ outside London!"

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "London" has a more bouncy image around the world than does "Britain", "UK", or heaven-forbid "England". If we are granted the mercy of an "Exit from Brexit", the next sensible step in my view would be to rename the whole country "London".

Comment: When I was a kid growing up in south London, one by one my socially aspirational aunts and uncles moved outside the then city boundary and gave themselves airs that they lived in "Surrey" or "Kent". On April 1st 1965, the London Government Act 1963 caused London to reach out and grab them back, when Kingston on Thames, Croydon and Bromley became London Boroughs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the grammar of that sentence is ambiguous, though the meaning is not.

However, if you replace *London* by some city or town that is known to have multiple beaches, then the presence of the definite article in front of *beach* (***the*** beach) makes the adverbial reading more likely: the alternative would tend to imply that there is only one beach in that locality.

*In Malibu* is a **preposition phrase** (PP). Although a PP can function as an [**adverbial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial#The_form_of_adverbials), it can never be an **adjective phrase,** since the [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)) of an adjective phrase must be an adjective. (In the terminology used here, a phrase whose head is an adverb would be called an **adverb phrase,** see e.g. [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31637/differences-between-adverb-phrase-adverbial-and-adjunct) for more.)

**A simpler sentence**

Let's consider the simpler sentence

[1]  *I run an Italian restaurant near the beach **in Malibu.***

(As in, [**Malibu, California**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malibu,_California).)

As I said, we can read the PP *in Malibu* in two different ways.

**The reading in which it is an adverbial**

In one reading, the PP *in Malibu* is an adverbial. This reading is the only possible one if this PP is fronted:

[2] ***In Malibu,*** I run an Italian restaurant near the beach.

**The reading in which it is a post-head modifier in an NP**

In another reading, we interpret the whole word group

[3] *an Italian restaurant near the beach in Malibu*

as a noun phrase (NP).

I don't know how to force that reading while keeping *in Malibu* as a PP. The closest I can come up with is

[4] *I run an Italian restaurant near **the beach that is located in Malibu.***

<sup>One tricky issue, which [4] makes manifest, is the definite article. Malibu has many beaches; indeed, I have been unable to think of a city that has a beach, but only a single one; normally it's either none or multiple ones. This is not a problem in the adverbial interpretation, because we routinely say *the beach* even when we don't really have a particular one in mind (A: *Let's go to the beach!* B: *Which one?* A: *I don't know, either the one we went to last week, or the one a bit more to the north.*) But when you say *the beach in Malibu,* or, even more clearly, *the beach that is located in Malibu,* you are implying that there is only one such beach. So you should either change *the beach* to *a beach,* or supply additional specifying information, such as *the beach that is located at the southern edge of Malibu* (alternatively, the broader context could provide such additional information; maybe the reader already knows which beach in Malibu you mean). I will ignore this issue in what follows, but it seems to me that this could make the adverbial reading more likely if the locality has multiple beaches, like Malibu does.</sup>

In [3], the head is *restaurant,* and it has the following PP as a post-head modifier:

[5] *near the beach in Malibu*

That PP, in turn, consists of the head, the preposition *near* (that word can also be an adjective, but here it's a preposition), and the complement which is the NP

[6] *the beach in Malibu*

The NP [6] has the head *beach* and a post-head modifier, namely the PP *in Malibu.*

The only adjective phrase in [1] is *Italian.*